# sudo: stop: command not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, server, shiny

I'm running a shiny app on an amazon web services instance using shiny-server. I wanted to stop the shiny-server in order to set up password protection but when I was following a protocol that said to type `sudo stop shiny-server` I got this error sudo: stop: command not found.

I tried to look into it and tried to install `sudo apt-get install upstart-sysv` but now my error is stop: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused.

the aws instance is ubuntu 16.04, any help is appreciated

Comment: sudo systemctl stop shiny-server

Comment: That worked! Thanks! Do you know the reason `sudo stop shiny-server` doesn't work anymore?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `sudo systemctl stop shiny-server`

Most major Linux distros, including Ubuntu 15.04+, now use systemd for management and configuration.

Earlier versions of Ubuntu used upstart (where the command was `sudo stop shiny-server`).

For more, see [shiny-server documentation](http://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#stopping-and-starting).